# select returns only one item from XML

Tags: arrays, xml, sql-server-2008

I have an xml array. when using select it only returns the first value. Here is my code . Whats wrong with my code.

```
 DECLARE @xml xml;
SET @xml =N'<root>
  <Id>68890</Id>
  <Id>68900</Id>
</root>';

SELECT

    replicateIdXml.replicateIds.value('Id[1]','bigint') as id

  FROM @xml.nodes('/root') AS replicateIdXml (replicateIds)
```

It only returns the first row .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. Your `.nodes()` returns all `root` element of the first level row-wise. But there is only one `root`-element... Than you pick the first `Id`-element, which is the one you see.

You have to let `.nodes()` return all `Id`-elements row-wise:

```
DECLARE @xml xml;
SET @xml =
N'<root>
  <Id>68890</Id>
  <Id>68900</Id>
</root>';

SELECT  
    replicateIdXml.replicateIds.value('.','bigint') as id
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/Id') AS replicateIdXml (replicateIds)
```

Comment: thank you very much . I would appreciate how you came up with this answer. I googled a lot but could n't find examples with single column xml. If there's any other link please provide.I want to know your way of thinking.

Comment: @shanavascet, well this is what `.nodes()`[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx] is meant to do... Follow the link and read the docs about `.nodes()`, `.query()`, `.value()` and `.modify()`. If you want it hardcore you can read about FLWOR...